# JWT error IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider C#

Tags: c#, jwt

I'm trying to run my app but it get stuck with the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException   HResult=0x80131515   Message=IDX10634:
>   Unable to create the SignatureProvider. Algorithm: '[PII is hidden by
>   default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true
>   to reveal it.]', SecurityKey: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the
>   'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]' 
>   is not supported.

Where

> Algorithm is RS256

It stucks on executing this instruction: `var sectoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);`

What does it mean? What went wrong in my code? How can I solve this?

---

Here's my code:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//...
public class TokenManager
{
    private string unencoded_key = "CaptainDeadpool";
    private string encoded_key = "CaptainDeadpool";
//...
    public TokenManager()
    {
        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unencoded_key);
        encoded_key = Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }


    public string CreateFromUsername(string usr, int? timer)
    {
        if (timer == null) {  timer = 30; }
        double timeadd = Convert.ToDouble(timer);

        var secret = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded_key);
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var actual = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usr) }),
            Expires = actual.AddMinutes(timeadd),

            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)
        };

        var sectoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var stringtoken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(sectoken);

        return stringtoken;
    }
//...
```

Here's my `tokenDescriptor`'s content while issuing the error:

[image: CONTENT]

Comment: Setting the following flag is hugely helpful in debugging situations like this. It will repleace the [PII is Hidden] with the actual error. Just remember to remove the flag before releasing to production: IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No idea what that error message means, but it doesn't matter I think, because your code is logically wrong. RSA is assymetric algorithm, but you are trying to use `SymmetricSecurityKey` with it.

So either use another (symmetric) signature algorithm (and ensure that your key size is valid for this algorithm), for example:

```
// adjust key size
private string unencoded_key = "CaptainDeadpool!";
private string encoded_key = "CaptainDeadpool!";
// ...
SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
    new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret), 
    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
```

Or provide valid key, for example:

```
private readonly RSA _rsa;
public TokenManager() {
    // import instead of creating new, if necessary
    _rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);            
}
// ...

SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
    new RsaSecurityKey(_rsa), 
    SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)
```

Comment: I tried the first solution but it hasn't solved the issue. The second one worked fine! Just a quick question,...what's "(2048)" for? Can I use my secret key instead?

Comment: 2048 is a size of private key. Assymetric algorithm uses 2 keys - public and private (for that reason you cannot use your secret as is). I set it to 2048 because that's a requirement of `SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature`.

Comment: For first "solution" to work you need to adjust your secret size as I said. For example, change your secret to `CaptainDeadpool!` (one additional character)

Comment: @Evk it was indeed problem with short "secret", at least for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when using hmacSha256. if your security key is too short, you may receive that error. I increased the size of the secret secureKey and that resolved my problem.

```
 var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("You_Need_To_Provide_A_Longer_Secret_Key_Here"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The key must have at least **32 characters.**

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error when I installed .net 8.
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: IDX10720: Unable to create KeyedHashAlgorithm for algorithm

So the solution is true as per the above response which was written by Mehdi
"The key must have at least **32** characters."
Like below

```
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("b693a53f-ad24-4fb0-bca0-92f56ae6406b"));
```